# Format C# DateTime

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, formatting

I have a bit of code that display the date within a text field as shown below

```
textField.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

It shows as

11/03/2011

anyone know how I could format here to show it as

11/03/11

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

Yes. Take a look at this [Date and Time formatting page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Or: `theDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")`

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

```
string strFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
textField.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(strFormat);
```

note that the format string is case-sensitive, make sure you use capital 'M's for month, otherwise it will consider 'minutes' for 'm'.
More general help about datetime formatting:

- MMM:     display three-letter month
- MM:      display two-digit month
- ddd:     display three-letter day of the WEEK
- d:       display day of the MONTH
- HH:      display two-digit hours on 24-hour scale
- mm:  display two-digit minutes
- yyyy:   display four-digit year

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

But you need to remember that `ToShortDateString()` is culture sensitive, returning different strings depending on the regional settings of the computer - the above is not.

You could change the settings on your computer, in Windows 7, you will find the Short Date format under `Region and Language` in the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative if you don't like format strings.

```
var fp = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
textField.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(fp.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```